# Problem with filebeat yml file on Windows

Tags: filebeat

I am quite new to the Elastic stack and trying to experiment with visualization of apache log files in Kibana. I am using filebeat to ingest the apache logs. However when I run `.\filebeat.exe setup -e`, I get the following error:

```
2019-02-05T20:53:10.515+0530    INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:165     Elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2019-02-05T20:53:10.520+0530    INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:721     Connected to Elasticsearch version 6.6.0
2019-02-05T20:53:10.520+0530    INFO    kibana/client.go:118    Kibana url: http://localhost:5601
2019-02-05T20:53:10.567+0530    WARN    fileset/modules.go:388  X-Pack Machine Learning is not enabled
2019-02-05T20:53:10.572+0530    ERROR   instance/beat.go:911    Exiting: 1 error: error loading config file: invalid con
fig: yaml: line 4: did not find expected hexdecimal number
```

My filebeat.yml file looks like this:

```
filebeat.inputs:

- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths: C:\Users\bigdataadmin\Downloads\ApacheLogs\*


#============================= Filebeat modules ===============================

filebeat.config.modules:

  path: C:\Program Files\Filebeat\modules.d\*.yml
  reload.enabled: true
  reload.period: 60s

#==================== Elasticsearch template setting ==========================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3

setup.kibana:
  host: "localhost:5601"

output.elasticsearch:

  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]


# Configure processors to enhance or manipulate events generated by the beat.

processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

I also checked the yml on http://www.yamllint.com/ but didn't find any problems. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with line 4 of this file.

I am using filebeat 6.6

Answer (score 1):

The path key(on line 4) is an array. So you need to represent an array there.

Example :

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - C:\Users\bigdataadmin\Downloads\ApacheLogs\*
```

Please be very cautious about the data type you are representing in such config files, I had made the same mistake while I was working on Filebeat and I had to spend a lot of time for a small mistake...

Comment: thanks, but it turned out to be that I had to wrap my paths in single quotes.